# No visible binding for global variable Note in R CMD check

Tags: r, package

I noticed in checking a package that I obtain notes "no visible binding for global variable" when I use functions like `subset` that use verbatim names of list elements as arguments.

For example with a data frame:

> foo <- data.frame(a=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),b=1:3)

I can do silly things like:

```
subset(foo,a)
transform(foo,a=b)
```

Which work as expected. The R code check in R CMD however doesn't understand that these refer to elements and complains about there not being any visible bindings of global variables.

While this works ok, I don't really like having notes in my package and prefer for it to pass the check with no errors, warnings and notes at all. I also don't really want to rework my code too much. Is there a way to write these codes so that it is clear the arguments do not refer to global variables?

Comment: This may have some justification in making packages "more compilable" for the sake of future R evolution...

Comment: I note that this question has been duplicated more recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when but the answers there have further information which others may find useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle R CMD check "no visible binding for global variable" notes when my ggplot2 syntax is sensible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To get it past `R CMD check` you can either :

- Use `get("b")` (but that is onerous)
- Place `a=b=NULL` somewhere higher up in your function (that's what I do)

There was a thread on r-devel a while ago where somebody from r-core basically said (from memory) "NOTES are ok, you know. The assumption is that the author checked it and is ok with the NOTE.". But, I agree with you. I do prefer to have CRAN checks return a clean "OK" on all platforms.  That way the user is left in no doubt that it passes checks ok.

EDIT :

Here is the [r-devel thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-CMD-check-tells-me-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-what-does-it-mean-tp1837236p1995245.html) I was remembering (from April 2010). So that appears to suggest that there are some situations where there is no known way to avoid the NOTE, but that's ok.

Comment: Thanks. I will use this until I have time to recode in a proper way:)

Comment: I'm not sure there is a proper way ;)  I think of the `a=b=NULL` thing as like C variable declaration. It makes me think a bit harder and has caught some bugs for me, so I don't mind it.

Comment: @MattDowle Seems like the opposite of C variable declaration, because it's saying to the user "these are NULL" when in fact the function will rely on them being not NULL as accessed.

Comment: thanks, this one has been annoying me for a long time when using `:=` inside data.table driven functions.

Comment: According to [this post](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1714), using `utils::globalVariables()` as outlined in @seancarmody's answer is the correct way to address this issue.

Answer (score 17):

This is one of the potential "unanticipated consequences" of using `subset` non-interactively.  As it says in the Warning section of `?subset`:

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   ‘[’, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument
>   ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.

Comment: Think the question might be more general than just `subset`. I've seen it a few times.

Comment: For robust functions avoid calling functions that use non-standard evaluation.

Comment: @hadley, but what about calls to `foreach`?... These still provoke the same Note.

Comment: @StevieP Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 12):

From R version 2.15.1 onwards there is a way around this:

```
if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")  utils::globalVariables(c("a", "othervar"))
```

Comment: yikes.. that's quite a side-effect just to to fake subset being evaluated correctly... Be nice if CRAN just allowed authors to mark notes about apparently (but not actually) missing globals as spurious…

Answer (score 9):

As per the warning section of `?subset` it is better to use subset interactively, and `[` for programming.

I would replace a command like

`subset(foo,a)`

with

`foo[foo$a]`

or if foo is a dataframe:

`foo[foo$a, ]`

you might also like to use `with` if foo is a dataframe and the expression to be evaluated is complex:

`with(foo, foo[a, ])`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `with` will cause the exact same problem since `a` is still not defined in the environment, only in the data.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and traced it to my ggplot2 section.

This code provided the error:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = spec.df, ggplot2::aes(E.avg, fraction)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
    ggplot2::ggtitle(paste0(title))
```

Adding the data name to the parameters eliminated the not:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = spec.df, ggplot2::aes(spec.df$E.avg, spec.df$fraction)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
    ggplot2::ggtitle(paste0(title))
```