# How can I handle R CMD check "no visible binding for global variable" notes when my ggplot2 syntax is sensible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

*EDIT: Hadley Wickham points out that I misspoke. R CMD check is throwing NOTES, not Warnings. I'm terribly sorry for the confusion. It was my oversight.*

### The short version

`R CMD check` throws this note every time I use [sensible plot-creation syntax](https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG/blob/dev/R/granovagg.contr.R#L254-265) in ggplot2:

```
no visible binding for global variable [variable name]
```

I understand why R CMD check does that, but it seems to be criminalizing an entire vein of otherwise sensible syntax. I'm not sure what steps to take to get my package to pass `R CMD check` and get admitted to CRAN.

### The background

Sascha Epskamp previously posted on [essentially the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096313/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note-in-r-cmd-check). The difference, I think, is that `subset()`'s manpage [says it's designed for interactive use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096313/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note-in-r-cmd-check/8096456#8096456).

In my case, the issue is not over `subset()` but over a core feature of `ggplot2`: the `data =` argument.

### An example of code I write that generates these notes

Here's [a sub-function](https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG/blob/dev/R/granovagg.contr.R#L254-265) in [my package](https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG) that adds points to a plot:

```
JitteredResponsesByContrast <- function (data) {
  return(
    geom_point(
             aes(
               x = x.values, 
               y = y.values
             ),
             data     = data,
             position = position_jitter(height = 0, width = GetDegreeOfJitter(jj))
    )
  )
}
```

`R CMD check`, on parsing this code, will say

```
granovagg.contr : JitteredResponsesByContrast: no visible binding for
  global variable 'x.values'
granovagg.contr : JitteredResponsesByContrast: no visible binding for
  global variable 'y.values'
```

### Why R CMD check is right

The check is technically correct. `x.values` and `y.values`

- Aren't defined locally in the function `JitteredResponsesByContrast()`
- Aren't pre-defined in the form `x.values <- [something]` either globally or in the caller.

Instead, they're variables within a dataframe that gets defined earlier and passed into the function `JitteredResponsesByContrast()`.

### Why ggplot2 makes it difficult to appease R CMD check

ggplot2 seems to encourage the use of a `data` argument. The data argument, presumably, is why this code will execute

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = cty), data = mpg)
p + geom_point()
```

but **this** code will produce an object-not-found error:

```
library(ggplot2)
hwy # a variable in the mpg dataset
```

### Two work-arounds, and why I'm happy with neither

#### The NULLing out strategy

[Matthew Dowle recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096882/180626) setting the problematic variables to NULL first, which in my case would look like this:

```
JitteredResponsesByContrast <- function (data) {
  x.values <- y.values <- NULL # Setting the variables to NULL first
  return(
    geom_point(
             aes(
               x = x.values, 
               y = y.values
             ),
             data     = data,
             position = position_jitter(height = 0, width = GetDegreeOfJitter(jj))
    )
  )
}
```

I appreciate this solution, but I dislike it for three reasons.

1. it serves no additional purpose beyond appeasing `R CMD check`.
2. it doesn't reflect intent. It raises the expectation that the `aes()` call will see our now-NULL variables (it won't), while obscuring the real purpose (making R CMD check aware of variables it apparently wouldn't otherwise know were bound)
3. The problems of 1 and 2 multiply because every time you write a function that returns a plot element, you have to add a confusing NULLing statement

#### The with() strategy

You can use `with()` to explicitly signal that the variables in question can be found inside some larger environment. In my case, using `with()` looks like this:

```
JitteredResponsesByContrast <- function (data) {
  with(data, {
      geom_point(
               aes(
                 x = x.values, 
                 y = y.values
               ),
               data     = data,
               position = position_jitter(height = 0, width = GetDegreeOfJitter(jj))
      )
    }
  )
}
```

This solution works. But, I don't like this solution because it doesn't even work the way I would expect it to. If `with()` were really solving the problem of pointing the interpreter to where the variables are, then I shouldn't even *need* the `data =` argument. But, `with()` doesn't work that way:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + with(mpg, geom_point(aes(x = hwy, y = cty)))
p # will generate an error saying `hwy` is not found
```

So, again, I think this solution has similar flaws to the NULLing strategy:

1. I still have to go through every plot element function and wrap the logic in a `with()` call
2. The `with()` call is misleading. I still need to supply a `data =` argument; all `with()` is doing is appeasing `R CMD check`.

### Conclusion

The way I see it, there are three options I could take:

1. Lobby CRAN to ignore the notes by arguing that they're "spurious" (pursuant to [CRAN policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html#Submission)), and do that every time I submit a package
2. Fix my code with one of two undesirable strategies (NULLing or `with()` blocks)
3. Hum really loudly and hope the problem goes away

None of the three make me happy, and I'm wondering what people suggest I (and other package developers wanting to tap into ggplot2) should do.

Comment: I like #1 and #3.

Comment: @BenBolker those are my go-to techniques too.

Comment: There is a 4th option: modify 'R CMD check' and submit a patch to r-devel for consideration. I suspect you'll find it's quite difficult (and possibly impossible) to detect which are spurious and which aren't. If anyone came up with a piece of code to do that, then ...

Comment: Another strategy is to use `aes_string`

Comment: This seems to be a problem with `transform` and `subset` too (not 100% sure, but it makes sense).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475309/in-r-is-it-possible-to-suppress-note-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable for dealing with this problem with reference classes (it was incorrectly marked as a dup)

Comment: This is also a problem with the base graphics::curve function that takes a placeholder "x" variable.

Comment: It's a problem with defining column names with `base::data.frame()` as well...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Have you tried with `aes_string` instead of `aes`? This should work, although I haven't tried it:

```
aes_string(x = 'x.values', y = 'y.values')
```

Comment: just a warning: `aes` does while `aes_string` doesn't define positional parameters `x` and `y`.

Comment: Just another warning. aes_string does not allow you to use functions to manipulate the x and y values. Say that you would like to log transform y in which case aes_string(x = 'x.values', y='log(y.values)') of course doesn't work. I use these kind of transformations a lot myself so aes_string is not always an option for me.

Comment: Perhaps this answer (and the one with the most votes) should be updated since the documentation of `aes_string` says: "All these functions are soft-deprecated. Please use tidy evaluation idioms instead (see the quasiquotation section in aes() documentation)." (ggplot2 version 3.2.1). That probably makes `rlang::.data` the best candidate to silence these notes.

Comment: @Vandenman Indeed, [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#eliminating-r-cmd-check-notes-1) seems to now be the preferred way to bypass these CRAN notes, however, this comes at the cost of importing yet another package...

Comment: @Vandenman Although, after a bit more reading, it seems that the import of `rlang` can be avoided by explicitly declaring the `.data` pronoun as `utils::globalVariables(".data")` (e.g., as discussed [here](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html#where-does-data-live-)).

Comment: Just here to note that `aes_string` has been deprecated since ggplot2 v3.0

Comment: Update to the hint from @alanocallaghan : using `aes_string` now actually generates a warning, making it unuseful for CRAN appeasement purposes.

Comment: It's irrelevant now, but per @Dr.Mike 's comment, you could actually do transforms in `aes_string`, eg `library(ggplot2); ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x="mpg", y="log(cyl)")) + geom_point()`. It's a real shame they deprecated it imo

Answer (score 104):

You have two solutions:

- Rewrite your code to avoid non-standard evaluation. For ggplot2, this means using `aes_string()` instead of `aes()` (as described by Harlan)
- Add a call to `globalVariables(c("x.values", "y.values"))` somewhere in the top-level of your package.

You should strive for 0 NOTES in your package when submitting to CRAN, even if you have to do something slightly hacky. This makes life easier for CRAN, and easier for you.

(Updated 2014-12-31 to reflect my latest thoughts on this)

Comment: there's now `utils::globalVariables` to prevent those notes (but don't forget `if (getRversion() >= "2.15.1")` or the package will really fail)

Comment: `globalVariables` is a hideous hack and I will never use it.

Comment: For what is worth, my package submission was rejected because of these notes and was told to use the utils::globalVariables function. Since I am not in a position to argue, that is what I did.

Comment: My package was also rejected with that argument. We really need to get the gate keepers over at CRAN to remove this restriction. It's wasting everybody's time.

Comment: I agree that it would be best to ignore them, but my code uses lots of `ggplot` and `data.table`, and thus has *tons* of these warnings, which have kept me from noticing other more important warnings that really were problems I needed to fix.

Comment: @hadley you shouldn't say you'll never use things when only two years later you think it's fine

Comment: new year resolution? I'll keep my eyes open for `ggplot::scale_dualAxis.sqrt` and 3D pie charts with fill patterns.

Comment: @hadley For the record I agree more with the 2012 you than the present you. I don't know what made you change your mind but to me globalVariables indeed feels like a "hideous hack"..

Comment: @Dr.Mike it's still a hideous hack, but you just have to suck it up if you want your package on CRAN

Comment: @Dr.Mike, @hadley, perhaps `suppressForeignCheck` can solve this issue, see my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30028702/1328355

Comment: Is there a way to automate getting the correct call to `globalVariables` with only variables in dplyr pipelines, and not the actual mistakes?

Comment: Note that `aes_string()` is deprecated and so you should remove it... Remains the `globalVariables` solution.

Answer (score 34):

This question has been asked and answered a while ago but just for your information, since [version 2.1.0](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases) there is another way to get around the notes: `aes_(x=~x.values,y=~y.values).`

Comment: Just a note that `aes_()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0.

Answer (score 34):

In 2019, the best way to get around this is to use the `.data` prefix from the `rlang` package, which also gets exported to `ggplot2`. This tells R to treat `x.values` and `y.values` as columns in a `data.frame` (so it won't complain about undefined variables).

Note: This works best if you have predefined columns names that you know will exist in you data input

```r
#' @importFrom ggplot2 .data
my_func <- function(data) {
    ggplot(data, aes(x = .data$x, y = .data$y))
}
```

EDIT: Updated to export `.data` from `ggplot2` instead of `rlang` based off @Noah comment

Comment: Note that `.data` is exported from `ggplot2` so you don't need to add `rlang` as an separate dependency.

Comment: `.data` is explained nicely at [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Now deprecated, love the sheer frequency at which tidyverse will ditch stuff like this making me rewrite packages https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/10/tidyselect-1-2-0/

Comment: Interestingly @alanocallaghan, that article only references `.data` use in `dplyr` not `ggplot2`. When I try to use their fix of just quoting the column names in the `ggplot()` call, I don't get what I want.

Answer (score 14):

If

```
getRversion() >= "3.1.0"
```

You can add a call at the top level of the package:

```
utils::suppressForeignCheck(c("x.values", "y.values"))
```

from:

```
help("suppressForeignCheck")
```

Comment: That's a fair solution. Thanks! I'd considered this, but the problem is that I have a great many variables like `x.values` and `y.values`, so I'd have to register ALL of them.

Comment: Yes I agree, its not ideal

Comment: Agreed. But again, thanks for your answer submission!

Comment: That is not what `suppressForeignCheck` is used for

Comment: Where is actually the **top level**? In which file do I add this command?

Comment: @bquast ... any reply for @drmariod? im also unsure about this.

Comment: By custom, this is put in a `zzz.R` file in `./R/`. For example, https://github.com/HughParsonage/grattan/blob/master/R/zzz.R

Comment: @hadley, what is it used for? help("suppressForeignCheck") seems to imply it is for a " run-time calculated native symbol", but what the heck is that?

Answer (score 8):

Add this line of code to the file in which you provide package-level documentation:

```
if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")  utils::globalVariables(c("."))
```

Example [here](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/blob/master/R/googlesheets.R#L15-L16)

Comment: The comment in the code you linked to says that this is just to suppress notes for places where `.` is used in pipelines, not for other variables or the columns in the OP's data frame. Would the same code apply to column names?

Comment: @camille I had a pilfer through some source code, and I can't spot anything, so based on that, I don't *think* anything else is necessary (although I will update if I find something). Perhaps the best way to know for sure is to check with something like `R CMD check --as-cran` and see if it produces notes

Answer (score 2):

Because the manual for ?aes_string says

> All these functions are soft-deprecated. Please use tidy evaluation
> idioms instead (see the quasiquotation section in aes()
> documentation).

So I read that page, and came up with this pattern:

```
ggplot2::aes(x = !!quote(x.values),
             y = !!quote(y.values))
```

It is about as fugly as an IIFE, and mixes base expressions with tidy-bang-bangs. But does not require the global variables workaround, either, and doesn't use anything that is deprecated afaict. It seems like it also works with calculations in aesthetics and the derived variables like `..count..`

Answer (score 1):

how about using get()?

```
geom_point(
         aes(
           x = get('x.values'), 
           y = get('y.values')
         ),
         data     = data,
         position = position_jitter(height = 0, width = GetDegreeOfJitter(jj))
)
```