# When writing functions for an R package, should I avoid non standard evaluation?

Tags: r, dplyr

While testing the code of a package with R CMD check the following NOTE appears for every variables used inside dplyr functions using non standard evaluation: `" no visible binding for global variable ..."` For example if I used

```
cars %>% mutate(speedplusone = speed +1)
```

R CMD check would give the NOTE:

```
no visible binding for global variable speed
```

The question of removing these notes has been asked already and there is a [reply by Hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429344/2641825) giving the option to either rewrite calls using standard evaluation or to fake the existence of those variable with a call to `globalVariables()`.

According to Hadley's answer, I can remove those R CMD Check notes by using standard evaluation, replacing `mutate` by `mutate_` :

```
cars %>% mutate_(speedplusone = ~speed +1)
```

Should I rewrite all dplyr function calls in the package to avoid non standard evaluation completely?

Comment: For several months I tried very hard to avoid non standard evaluation in my packages (mostly because I wasn't clever enough to figure out how to make `globalVariables()` work), but it's been a massive headache.  I wouldn't bother.  I have found it infinitely easier just to write my functions with NSE and then go back and edit my `globalVariables` when I do my package check.

Comment: I would not like changing my code only because the check returns false positives (and those are only notes after all). I'd take the `globalVariables` option.

Comment: You IMO should use the `mutate_` that being said in my own packages it can be annoying and using `speed <- NULL` in the function at the begining fixes this.

Comment: Is it *actually* safe to use the underscored versions of the functions? I thought those were deprecated and therefore couldn't be relied on to stick around.