# How to replace the dot-dot notation in `ggplot2::geom_histogram(`y = ..density..`)`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, histogram, density-plot

Consider this basic ggplot2 example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.4.0'
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))
#> Warning: The dot-dot notation (`..density..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `after_stat(density)` instead.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

The dot dot notation is deprecated. So I tried the following, as recommended:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

But within a package this produces an R CMD check no visible binding note:

```r
#> nice_density: no visible binding for global variable 'density'.
```

Now I know it’s possible to define global variables with `utils::globalVariables` or define as `NULL` earlier, but I understand that these are not the preferred solution. So here are my various attempts:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(stats::density)))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Error in `geom_histogram()`:
#> ! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error in `map_statistic()`:
#> ! Aesthetics must be valid computed stats.
#> ✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
#> ✖ `y = after_stat(stats::density)`
#> ℹ Did you map your stat in the wrong layer?

#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>   2. │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>   3. │   ├─base (local) tryCatchOne(...)
#>   4. │   │ └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   5. │   └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh])
#>   6. │     └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>   7. │       └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   8. ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   9. ├─base::saveRDS(...)
#>  10. ├─base::do.call(...)
#>  11. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(...)
#>  12. └─global `<fn>`(input = base::quote("waspy-bunny_reprex.R"))
#>  13.   └─rmarkdown::render(input, quiet = TRUE, envir = globalenv(), encoding = "UTF-8")
#>  14.     └─knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
#>  15.       └─knitr:::process_file(text, output)
#>  16.         ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  17.         ├─knitr:::process_group(group)
#>  18.         └─knitr:::process_group.block(group)
#>  19.           └─knitr:::call_block(x)
#>  20.             └─knitr:::block_exec(params)
#>  21.               └─knitr:::eng_r(options)
#>  22.                 ├─knitr:::in_input_dir(...)
#>  23.                 │ └─knitr:::in_dir(input_dir(), expr)
#>  24.                 └─knitr (local) evaluate(...)
#>  25.                   └─evaluate::evaluate(...)
#>  26.                     └─evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
#>  27.                       ├─evaluate (local) handle(...)
#>  28.                       │ └─base::try(f, silent = TRUE)
#>  29.                       │   └─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  30.                       │     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  31.                       │       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  32.                       │         └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  33.                       ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  34.                       ├─base::withVisible(value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible))
#>  35.                       └─knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
#>  36.                         └─knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
#>  37.                           ├─base::withVisible(knit_print(x, ...))
#>  38.                           ├─knitr::knit_print(x, ...)
#>  39.                           └─knitr:::knit_print.default(x, ...)
#>  40.                             └─evaluate (local) normal_print(x)
#>  41.                               ├─base::print(x)
#>  42.                               └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
#>  43.                                 ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
#>  44.                                 └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
#>  45.                                   └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
#>  46.                                     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
#>  47.                                     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  48.                                     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  49.                                     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  50.                                     │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  51.                                     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  52.                                     └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
#>  53.                                       └─l$map_statistic(d, plot)
#>  54.                                         └─ggplot2 (local) map_statistic(..., self = self)
#>  55.                                           └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  56.                                             └─rlang::abort(...)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes_string(y = after_stat("density")))
#> Warning: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0.
#> ℹ Please use tidy evaluation ideoms with `aes()`
#> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type <function>.
#> Defaulting to continuous.
#> Error in `geom_histogram()`:
#> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
#> ! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
#> ✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
#> ✖ `y = density`
#> ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?

#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>   2. │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>   3. │   ├─base (local) tryCatchOne(...)
#>   4. │   │ └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   5. │   └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh])
#>   6. │     └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>   7. │       └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   8. ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   9. ├─base::saveRDS(...)
#>  10. ├─base::do.call(...)
#>  11. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(...)
#>  12. └─global `<fn>`(input = base::quote("waspy-bunny_reprex.R"))
#>  13.   └─rmarkdown::render(input, quiet = TRUE, envir = globalenv(), encoding = "UTF-8")
#>  14.     └─knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
#>  15.       └─knitr:::process_file(text, output)
#>  16.         ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  17.         ├─knitr:::process_group(group)
#>  18.         └─knitr:::process_group.block(group)
#>  19.           └─knitr:::call_block(x)
#>  20.             └─knitr:::block_exec(params)
#>  21.               └─knitr:::eng_r(options)
#>  22.                 ├─knitr:::in_input_dir(...)
#>  23.                 │ └─knitr:::in_dir(input_dir(), expr)
#>  24.                 └─knitr (local) evaluate(...)
#>  25.                   └─evaluate::evaluate(...)
#>  26.                     └─evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
#>  27.                       ├─evaluate (local) handle(...)
#>  28.                       │ └─base::try(f, silent = TRUE)
#>  29.                       │   └─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  30.                       │     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  31.                       │       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  32.                       │         └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  33.                       ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  34.                       ├─base::withVisible(value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible))
#>  35.                       └─knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
#>  36.                         └─knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
#>  37.                           ├─base::withVisible(knit_print(x, ...))
#>  38.                           ├─knitr::knit_print(x, ...)
#>  39.                           └─knitr:::knit_print.default(x, ...)
#>  40.                             └─evaluate (local) normal_print(x)
#>  41.                               ├─base::print(x)
#>  42.                               └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
#>  43.                                 ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
#>  44.                                 └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
#>  45.                                   └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
#>  46.                                     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
#>  47.                                     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  48.                                     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  49.                                     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  50.                                     │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  51.                                     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  52.                                     └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
#>  53.                                       └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
#>  54.                                         └─ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
#>  55.                                           └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  56.                                             └─rlang::abort(...)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes_string(y = "density"))
#> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type <function>.
#> Defaulting to continuous.
#> Error in `geom_histogram()`:
#> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
#> ! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
#> ✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
#> ✖ `y = density`
#> ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?

#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>   2. │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>   3. │   ├─base (local) tryCatchOne(...)
#>   4. │   │ └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   5. │   └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh])
#>   6. │     └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>   7. │       └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>   8. ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   9. ├─base::saveRDS(...)
#>  10. ├─base::do.call(...)
#>  11. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(...)
#>  12. └─global `<fn>`(input = base::quote("waspy-bunny_reprex.R"))
#>  13.   └─rmarkdown::render(input, quiet = TRUE, envir = globalenv(), encoding = "UTF-8")
#>  14.     └─knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
#>  15.       └─knitr:::process_file(text, output)
#>  16.         ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  17.         ├─knitr:::process_group(group)
#>  18.         └─knitr:::process_group.block(group)
#>  19.           └─knitr:::call_block(x)
#>  20.             └─knitr:::block_exec(params)
#>  21.               └─knitr:::eng_r(options)
#>  22.                 ├─knitr:::in_input_dir(...)
#>  23.                 │ └─knitr:::in_dir(input_dir(), expr)
#>  24.                 └─knitr (local) evaluate(...)
#>  25.                   └─evaluate::evaluate(...)
#>  26.                     └─evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
#>  27.                       ├─evaluate (local) handle(...)
#>  28.                       │ └─base::try(f, silent = TRUE)
#>  29.                       │   └─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  30.                       │     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  31.                       │       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  32.                       │         └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  33.                       ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  34.                       ├─base::withVisible(value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible))
#>  35.                       └─knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
#>  36.                         └─knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
#>  37.                           ├─base::withVisible(knit_print(x, ...))
#>  38.                           ├─knitr::knit_print(x, ...)
#>  39.                           └─knitr:::knit_print.default(x, ...)
#>  40.                             └─evaluate (local) normal_print(x)
#>  41.                               ├─base::print(x)
#>  42.                               └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
#>  43.                                 ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
#>  44.                                 └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
#>  45.                                   └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
#>  46.                                     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
#>  47.                                     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  48.                                     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  49.                                     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  50.                                     │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
#>  51.                                     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  52.                                     └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
#>  53.                                       └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
#>  54.                                         └─ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
#>  55.                                           └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  56.                                             └─rlang::abort(...)
```

So what is the new, officially recommanded approach here?
There was a similar post a year ago but it received no answer.

[no visible binding for global variable 'density'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887466/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-density)

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Does `y = after_stat(.data[["density"]])` give a warning too? I think that this section of the vignette applies to `after_stat()` as well: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function

Comment: @teunbrand yeah, I included this in my original reprex but excluded it because it doesn't make sense because it doesn't refer to the data or a column name so of course it cannot find the colum "density" in the data.

```r
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `.data[["density"]]`:
! Column `density` not found in `.data`.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the "no visible binding" CMD nag by defusing a string-as-symbol argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(!!str2lang("density"))))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>