# How to solve "no visible binding for global variable 'x' "

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am building a package in R.
The first function, is a ggplot function containing x and y for the definition of the x and y axis `(aes(x,y))`.

After running the command `devtools::check()`, I am receiving this message

> "no visible binding for global variable 'x' "

even after adding `@importFrom ggplot2 aes`

I think that's because x and y are parameters for `aes`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: refer https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-solve-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note/28887 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when

Comment: Actually yes, but I was searching another strategy because I don't find putting these parameters as NULL is very "logic". That's why I was looking for another way to fix it

Comment: It feels somewhat 'hacky' but a workaround is a file in R, named globals.R or similar (up to you, but standard is globals.R), in which you call utils::globalVariables( c("name", "your", "variables"). Alternatively you can look into rlang::.data, but that's a bit out of scope here I feel.