# R devtools document error: object not found, but created in pipe by summarise()

Tags: r, dplyr, document, devtools, roxygen

I changed the name of my github package by removing an illegal underscore and it's caused everything to break. I've subsequently removed all except the 5 core scripts from /R/ but still can't get it to install.

The current problem is, when I `document()` I get

> Error in filter(check1, relocations >= bbdwindowsize): object
> 'relocations' not found

From here:

```
check1 <- data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(relocations = length(Datetime))
check2 <- filter(check1, relocations >= bbdwindowsize)
```

There's nothing wrong with this code. Does `document()` not understand `dplyr` coding style?

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the quick replies folks. Per MrFlick's [suggestion](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html):

```
# at top
#' @importFrom rlang .data
# then:
check1 <- data %>%
    group_by(.data$ID) %>%
    summarise(relocations = length(.data$Datetime))
check2 <- filter(check1, .data$relocations >= bbdwindowsize)
```

> Error in (check2 line): Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask
> context.

Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: See the "Eliminating R CMD check NOTEs" section of the [programming with dplyr guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: did you call `library(dplyr)` in that script? if not it might be trying to use `filter()` from the stats package

Comment: Thanks Flick, just tried that & updated question. Thanks Mike, not exactly, `#' @import dplyr` at the top instead

Comment: Is your code outside of a function? Is this supposed to be part of an "example" section? It does seem like the wrong `filter()` is being called but it's unclear exactly how your package code is organized,.

Comment: Thanks. I slapped `dplyr::` in front of everything around that area and that solved it (/ kicked the can down the road to the next issue with `document`)

Comment: @MrFlick if you want credit for the answer by all means put your comment as a proper answer and I'll tick it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No Rcheck doesn't understand.

One way to deal with that is to create fake global variables

```
globalVariables(c("relocations", [everything other symbol you used]))
```

in the package.R file of your package.

It had been advised by Hadley Wickham in the past ( [How can I handle R CMD check "no visible binding for global variable" notes when my ggplot2 syntax is sensible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when) ) and still passes RCheck

Through, the tidyverse tutorials nowaday recommend to import `rlang::.data` cf https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html or https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html .

Comment: Rather than create fake global variables, the current recommendation is to use the `.data` pronoun instead.

Comment: I had seen some recommandation by Hadley Wickham once but maybe things changed

Comment: Well, if you have a reference feel free to include it, but that sounds outdated at least according to the current [programming with dplyr guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when Found

Comment: A lot has changed since 2012. That was well before the `.data` pronoun existed. It would be better to follow the current best practices. Other answers in that thread are more up-to-date, ie https://stackoverflow.com/a/57496617/2372064

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick . You're right that it's better to follow the evolution of the best practices. However does your trick work if you want to keep the tidyverse as suggests, nor depends ?

Comment: Well if you are trying to use `dplyr` commands, then you'll have a dependency on `dplyr` so you'll have access to `.data`. But I don't immediately see why just using suggests would be a problem. You could just use `dplyr::.data` when you need to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243531/discussion-between-arnaud-feldmann-and-mrflick).