# Visual binding for using ddply in package-function in R

Tags: r, package, plyr

i have a comparable issue like already discussed 
here:
[No visible binding for global variable Note in R CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096313/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note-in-r-cmd-check)

In my case, I am using the function ddply in my
own package and when I check the R-package I get
a note that there is "no visible binding for global variable 'VARX'.

The adressed code line is:

```
subsample <- ddply(my_data, .(VARX), function(x){x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ]})
```

The variable VARX is a column in a dataframe that is provided by the
package (sysdata). What is good practice to improve that code 
for a proper R-package?

Comment: What do you need that is not already in the question you linked?

Comment: it was not clear to me that both mentioned approaches are also best practice for ddply. Maybe there is also a better approach for the use of ddply in programming...

Comment: Just use `"VARX"` instead

Comment: I voted to close as this is a duplicate of the question posted.  `plyr` was not a factor in the issue.  I had the same question myself a few months back.  Common question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `ddply`, it is just that `VARX` is not a valid object in the current workspace as it is a column in `my_data`. The suggestions in the question you linked also hold here, probably placing `VARX = NULL` somewhere before your call to `subsample <- ddply(my_data, .(VARX), function(x){x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ]})` will solve this problem as now `R CMD CHECK` sees that there is a `VARX` object. This also does not interfere with the call to `ddply` as scoping ensures that the `VARX` in `my_data` is used, and not the `VARX` in the global scope.