# R package compilation with dependency on data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create an R package with a function using the `J` of data.table.
When I run `R CMD check`, I have a NOTE : no visible global function definition for 'J'
although I've added data.table as a dependency in the DESCRIPTION file.

> Package: rfPred
>   Type: Package
>   Title: Assign rfPred functional prediction scores to a missense variants list
>   Version: 1.0
>   Date: 2013-03-14
>   Author: me
>   Maintainer:me
>   Depends: data.table
>   [..]

I've tried to use another function of the data.table package in the package I want to create, but I haven't the same problem as for J.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Could you show us your `description` file? Also which version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: You should also document how you are using `J`.

Comment: The Description file is the following :

Package: rfPred
Type: Package
Title: Assign rfPred functional prediction scores to a missense variants list 
Version: 1.0
Date: 2013-03-14
Author: me
Maintainer:me
Depends: data.table

Comment: And I'm using the version 1.8.8 of data.table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`J()` as an independent function has been removed from `data.table`.  It is only for use inside `DT[...]`, where it still works.  But for packages depending on `data.table` and using `J()` correctly, like yours, an extra step is required to avoid the NOTE (see below).

First the background and why `J()` was removed. Extracts from [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

#### v1.8.2 (Jul 2012) :

- The J() alias is now deprecated outside DT[...], but will still work
  inside
  DT[...], as in DT[J(...)].
  J() is conflicting with function J() in package XLConnect (#1747)
  and rJava (#2045). For data.table to change is easier, with some
  efficiency
  advantages too. The next version of data.table will issue a warning
  from J()
  when used outside DT[...]. The version after will remove it. Only
  then will
  the conflict with rJava and XLConnect be resolved.
  Please use data.table() directly instead of J(), outside DT[...].

#### v1.8.4 (Nov 2012) :

- J() now issues a warning (when used *outside* DT[...]) that using it
  outside DT[...] is deprecated. See item below in v1.8.2.
  Use data.table() directly instead of J(), outside DT[...]. Or,
  define
  an alias yourself. J() will continue to work *inside* DT[...] as
  documented.

#### v1.8.8 (now on CRAN, Mar 2013) :

- The J() alias is now removed *outside* DT[...], but will still work
  inside DT[...];
  i.e., DT[J(...)] is fine. As warned in v1.8.2 (see below in this
  file) and deprecated
  with warning() in v1.8.4. This resolves the conflict with function
  J() in package
  XLConnect (#1747) and rJava (#2045).
  Please use data.table() directly instead of J(), outside DT[...].

As an aside, there was also a recent related thread on r-devel :
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/conflict-between-rJava-and-data-table-tp4659935p4659984.html

**Now for the NOTE produced by `R CMD check` on your package**

Your package is using `J()` inside `DT[...]` and working fine. The only issue is the NOTE from R CMD check :

```
no visible global function definition for 'J'
```

Here are all the known options :

- Ignore the NOTE. (I don't like this either but just as an option). Only WARNING and ERROR have to be dealt with.
- Replace `J` by `list`. It's equivalent.
- Define `J=NULL` somewhere in your package. (We looked at `data.table` exporting `J=NULL` so you wouldn't have to but decided not to since any `data.table` user typing `J` at the prompt would see `NULL` which may be confusing.)
- Or use `?utils::globalVariables` as Ben Bolker suggested in comments.

Further background on this particular NOTE is in this related question :

**[No visible binding for global variable Note in R CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096313/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note-in-r-cmd-check)**

Comment: I'm using J() inside data.table, but the compilation program doesn't see it

Comment: How can I say to the R compilater that my package depends on J() ?

Comment: @user2169834 Then as DWin suggested, we really do need to see your line of code using `J()`. All I can think is that you're not using `J()` in quite the right way.

Comment: x is a data.table and my code is the following :  
variants[j:(j-1+nrow(scores)),]$rfPred<-x[J(scores[,1], scores[,2], scores[,3], scores[,4],scores[,5])]$rfPred

I can fix the problem in replacing J() by data.table() in my code, but I don't understand why the R compilator doesn't recognize J() although the function runs well.

Comment: `J <- NULL` will work; you can also use `tools::globalVariables` to work around the NOTE, if you want

Comment: @BenBolker Cool. `globalVariables()` is news to me, thanks. Found it in `utils:` btw.