# data.table does not play well with checkUsage

Tags: r, data.table

[`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/) is a wonderful package, which, alas, generates unwarranted warnings from [`checkUsage`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/codetools/) (the code comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132625/how-to-avoid-an-optimization-warning-in-data-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152161/understanding-optimisation-messages-on-assignment-by-reference-in-a-data-table)):

```
> library(compiler)
> compiler::enableJIT(3)
> dt <- data.table(a = c(rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5)), b=1:10, c=11:20, d=21:30, key="a")
> my.func <- function (dt) {
  dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = a]
  dt.out[, count := dt[, .N, by=a]$N]
  dt.out
}
> checkUsage(my.func)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘.SD’ (:2)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘a’ (:2)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘count’ (:3)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘.N’ (:3)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘a’ (:3)
> my.func(dt)
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.SD' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable 'a' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable 'count' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.N' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable 'a' 
   a  b  c   d count
1: 3 15 65 115     5
2: 4 40 90 140     5
```

The warnings about `a` can be avoided by replacing `by=a` with `by="a"`, but how do I deal with the other 3 warnings?

This matters to me because these warnings clutter the screen and obscure legitimate warnings. Since the warnings are issued on `my.func` invocation (when JIT compiler is enabled), not just by `checkUsage`, I am inclined to call this a [bug](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2723&group_id=240&atid=975).

Comment: Query: those are objects inside `my.func` , so why should they be considered `global` variables?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15411032/967840), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096882/967840)

Comment: I don't know `checkUsage`. If there's something I can change in `data.table` please let me know. Or maybe there's an option to `checkUsage`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: this is not just `checkUsage`, the JIT compiler issues the warning too

Comment: @sds In about 10 seconds of looking at `?enableJIT` I found `options` and `suppressUndefined`. Did you find it?  Raising it as a `data.table` bug already seems a little quick.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: I do _not_ want to `suppressUndefined`. I _do_ want to see those warnings, but only the legitimate ones.

Comment: @sds I replied to your reply that this note (not warning) is an old chestnut in the R community and probably beyond my ability to resolve. But I've left your `data.table` bug report open.

Comment: It seems unlikely that byte code compiling code that uses data.table will be of any benefit, since pretty much all the data.table code already uses compiled C code.

Comment: @hadley: my primary reason for compiling is the same as `checkUsage`: error detection before execution

Comment: @sds Given that `checkUsage` is purely heuristic driven, and it doesn't work well with any package that uses non-standard evaluation (e.g. data.table, ggplot2, plyr, ...), I doubt that the benefits out weigh the costs.  You'd be better off relying on unit testing.

Comment: Unit testing is orthogonal to this question.  I can unit-test the heck out of something, and still not notice that it's doing unsavory things to the global namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE** : Now resolved in v1.8.11. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> `.SD`,`.N`,`.I`,`.GRP` and `.BY` are now exported (as `NULL`). So that NOTEs aren't produced for them by `R CMD check` or `codetools::checkUsage` via `compiler::enableJIT()`. `utils::globalVariables()` was considered, but exporting chosen.
>       Thanks to Sam Steingold for raising, [#2723](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=2723&atid=975).

And to resolve the notes for the column name symbols `count` and `a`, they can both be wrapped with quotes (even on the LHS of `:=`). Using a fresh R session (since the notes were first time only) the following now produces no notes.

```
$ R
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> require(data.table)
Loading required package: data.table
data.table 1.8.11  For help type: help("data.table")
> library(compiler)
> compiler::enableJIT(3)
[1] 0
> dt <- data.table(a=c(rep(3,5),rep(4,5)), b=1:10, c=11:20, d=21:30, key="a")
> my.func <- function (dt) {
  dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "a"]
  dt.out[, "count" := dt[, .N, by="a"]$N]
  dt.out
}
> my.func(dt)
   a  b  c   d count
1: 3 15 65 115     5
2: 4 40 90 140     5
> checkUsage(my.func)
>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the only way at this time is

```
my.func <- function (dt) {
  .SD <- .N <- count <- a <- NULL  # avoid inappropriate warnings
  dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = a]
  dt.out[, count := dt[, .N, by=a]$N]
  dt.out
}
```

i.e., to bind locally the variables reported as unbound globals.

Thanks to @GSee for the links.