# R CMD check: no visible binding for global variable ‘mypkgdata’

Tags: r, package, cran

This question is slightly different from others on this subject -- I do indeed have a variable called "mypkgdata":

I am writing a package which ships with a data set. This data set is needed for calculations from within the package. In the DESCRIPTION file, I have specified "LazyData" for that purpose, such that the data set is always around when anyone loads the package. When I run the check, however, I get:

.getmodules2: no visible binding for global variable ‘mypkgdata’

What is the correct way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you have LazyData: TRUE in your DESCRIPTION file than the following should work:

```
x <- MyPackageName::mypkgdata
# ... your calculations using x
```

I get your note also, if I trie calling it without the MyPackageName:: part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have solved it. I create a custom environment in the package, load the data set in this environment, and wrote a function that returns the data set:

```
pkgEnv <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())

if(!exists("mypkgdata", pkgEnv)) {
  data("mypkgdata", package="mypkg", envir=pkgEnv)
}

getMyPkgData <- function() {
  pkgEnv[["mypkgdata"]]
}
```

And in the function that utilizes "mypkgdata", I write:

```
mypkgdata <- getMyPkgData()
```

Also, I gave up on lazy loading the data, as it is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think data from a package should not be flagged as invisible. However, a workaround is

```
if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")  utils::globalVariables("mypkgdata")
```

compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807914/3805440