# R: How to enable JIT compiler via script, not environment?

Tags: r, compilation, jit

I work on several R projects at the same time. One of them involves a simulation with a for-loop, which I hope to speed up by using a JIT-compiler. To do so, I added to the file *Rcmd_environ* in my R-directory/etc the lines [following this recommendation](http://www.drewdimmery.com/jit-compilation-in-r/).

```
R_COMPILE_PKGS=TRUE
R_ENABLE_JIT=3
```

Now I wonder, whether it is possible, to turn this on and off via a script. This way, I wouldn't have JIT-compilation in my other projects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the `compiler` library and then set the JIT level via calling the 'enableJIT` function.

For e.g. you can do

```
require(compiler)
enableJIT(3)
```

to get full JIT compilation.

Comment: thanks. I then get a lots of "Note: no visible binding for global variable xy". How is that to be understood?

Comment: I see that this is  rather no reason to worry, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096313/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note-in-r-cmd-check