# ggplot2 inside R packages: Notes during CRAN tests

Tags: r, ggplot2, cran

I am writing an R package that uses many `ggplot2` functions. The problem is that during CRAN tests I have many notes related to `ggplot` functions (see below). Given this situation, what is the best way to use `ggplot2` inside my functions in order to avoid these notes from CRAN?

An example of my code:

```
s1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(result,aes(x=slope,y=..density..),
            environment = environment())+
            geom_histogram(fill="lightyellow", 
                           alpha=.9,colour="grey60", size=.2) +
            geom_density(size=.2) +
            geom_vline(xintercept = slope.0,color="red",linetype=2,size=.7)+
            xlab("Estimated slopes")+
            theme(axis.text = element_text(size=14),
                  axis.title = element_text(size=16))
```

## CRAN notes:

> plot_influ_phylolm: no visible global function definition for ‘aes’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible binding for global variable ‘slope’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible binding for global variable
>     ‘..density..’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible global function definition for
>     ‘geom_histogram’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible global function definition for
>     ‘geom_density’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible global function definition for
>     ‘geom_vline’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible global function definition for ‘xlab’
>   plot_influ_phylolm: no visible global function definition for ‘theme’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to advocate avoiding rules, but while you're working out what where all the imports come from, you can always use the following for the `global variable`s:

```
slope <- density <- NULL
```

Add the above to the `.R` file which where these variables occur, before the variables appear as such in the code.
This question has been addressed in more detail on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096313/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note-in-r-cmd-check) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when).

As for the function definitions, it's tricky figure out exactly which functions you're going to be importing with a NAMESPACE as large as ggplot2, so perhaps easiest to import the whole package. I realize this is also not 'best practice' but it should get you past the CRAN checks. If using `roxygen` I typically use the description file for the package e.g. `myPkg_package.R`:

```
#' @name myPkg-package
#' @docType package
#' @keywords package
#'
#' @import ggplot2
#'
NULL
```

or, for selective import:

```
#' @importFrom ggplot2 theme
```

You will then want to edit the `DESCRIPTION` file to include something like:

```
Imports: ggplot2
```

You may even want to use `Depends:` for this, but dependencies on multiple packages (e.g. >4) are discouraged on CRAN.

You could of course specify the NAMESPACE every time e.g. change `theme` to  `ggplot2::theme` every time you call the function. Arguably this makes the code clearer, although it can get a little tedious and does add some slight overhead to execution time. This still requires you to declare the imports, as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanation. I will try that and let you know if worked!

Comment: Great this solved my problem! I used @importFrom ggplot2 aes geom_point etc. Now the notes are gone. The variables I solved with the NULL method. variable1 <- variable2 <- NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the relevant `Imports:` to `DESCRIPTION`, and `importFrom(...)` to `NAMESPACE`.  This has been discussed quite a bit recently, see for example [this thread on r-package-devel](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.packages.devel/209/focus=210) and its references to further discussion.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I will have a look at the thread and give you some feedback.