# utils::globalVariables(.) not applicable to R CMD CHECK note:no visible binding for global variable '.'

Tags: r, r-package, magrittr

[detailed explanation]

`utils::globalVariables(c("a", "othervar"))` is not applicable to my case because my var **is a DOT**
`So utils::globalVariables(.)`  gives me an error

After suggestion in comments from Hong, quoting did the trick, so:
`So utils::globalVariables(".")`
[end detailed explanation]

I've got an R package working ok on any machine is installed. Basically gets some information scraping a website.

URL is working ok and if installed anywhere the package functions are all of them working fine. Travis for continuous integration is building ok too.

```
    R CMD check results
    0 errors | 0 warnings | 1 note 

R CMD check succeeded
```

So, I'm Testing for submitting to CRAN but received one NOTE:

```
     no visible binding for global variable '.'
     Undefined global functions or variables:
     .
```

NAMESPACE file contains:

```
import(magrittr)
export(myfunction1)
export(myfunction2)
```

I guess this is a magrittr issue or a subtle part of code that is replacing strings (sample below) because there is no variable named dot.

```
 x <- gsub("^mechanical", "Mech.", x , ignore.case = T) %>%
      gsub("$", ")", . , ignore.case = T)
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807914/3817004) using `utils::globalVariables()`.

Comment: Uwe, please read my code carefully. Your suggestion is not applicable to my code because my variable is a DOT, so 
 utils::globalVariables(.) not working.

Comment: `utils::globalVariables(".")`

Comment: Quoting did the trick!! I'm so embarrassed...